# Jersey 2.4 Test with Spring Context Profile - DI not working

Tags: java, spring, rest, junit, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to configure a Jersey (2.4) test using Spring application context, using Spring profiles.

My test class is this:

```
public class OrderControllerTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);
        ApplicationResourceConfig config = new ApplicationResourceConfig();
        config.property("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:spring-context.xml");
        config.property("spring.profiles.active", "development");
        return config;
    }

...
```

Where `ApplicationResourceConfig` class is this:

```
public class ApplicationResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public ApplicationResourceConfig() {
        register(RequestContextFilter.class)
        .register(OrderController.class);
    }

...
```

and `OrderController` class is:

```
@Component
@Path("/order")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @PUT
    public Response createOrder(String order) {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
...
```

The problem is that DI is not working (`orderService` is `null`). The DI is working well in other tests (not Jersey-based). I suppose the reason could be that Spring profile is not correctly loaded, since Spring logs say:

```
426  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.active' in [systemProperties]
426  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.active' in [systemEnvironment]
426  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  - Could not find key 'spring.profiles.active' in any property source. Returning [null]
```

Is there anybody who can provide suggestions about this issue, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring profiles and Testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364112/spring-profiles-and-testing)

Comment: @nobeh Did you read carefully my question? _The DI is working well in other tests (not Jersey-based)_

Comment: I may be mistaken. If the problem is integrating Jersey 2+ with Spring Java Config, take a look at https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2038

Comment: I already read that webpage, actually there's no solution posted there

Comment: This may be an issue in Jersey/Spring integration - properties form resource config (i.e. `spring.profiles.active`) except `contextConfigLocation` are not visible to Spring (and they are certainly not set to system properties). Can you, please, comment on existing issue or create a new one?

Comment: Bug created on Jira: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2235

Answer (score 1):

I've created an example application how to integrate Jersey 2 with Spring Framework and also how to test these application. I hope it's helpful.

https://github.com/Hylke1982/jersey2-spring-test-example

-- Edit
I also created a new test framework that allows you to use test with Jersey, Spring Framework and Mockito.

https://github.com/Hylke1982/jersey-spring-exposed-test-framework-core

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is the configuration of Spring context in Jersey tests **using Spring profiles**