# Test or report to compare different profile configurations in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

how is it possible to compare different runtime configurations of a Spring-Boot application?

We use various yml files for different profiles and wanted to create a test that would show what configuration differences exist between two profiles.

Since the differences can be subject to different rules, the test is more likely to be a kind of 'diff', the result of which has to be manually checked.

Comment: See similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364112/spring-profiles-and-testing

Comment: @user7294900 Thanks for the feedback, the other question seems to be similar, but the essential aspect, the comparison of different resulting configurations at runtime, unfortunately will not be needled.